# Read hex in C# using IO

Tags: c#, hex

I'm moving from C# to Java and can't seem to find any information on this. I'm trying to read if a file using hex, in Java I use...

```
        String s = Integer.toHexString(hexIn);
        if(s.length() < 2){
            s = "0" + Integer.toHexString(hexIn);
        }
```

As I'm sure you know thats so if the byte read in is one characater long it adds a zero to make it hex, I wanna do the same thing for c# so far i have...

```
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileDirectory);
        long stickNoteLength = fileDirectory.Length;

        int hexIn;
        String hex = "";

        for (int i = 0; (hexIn = reader.Read()) != -1; i++)
        {

        }
```

Now I'm stuck, sorry if this is a simple question  and thanks for you help :)

Comment: Isn't 0 for octal and 0x for hexadecimal?

Comment: So, you need that numbers from 0 to 15 will be always 00, 01, ..., 0F (with additional 0)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read hex in C# using IO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612437/read-hex-in-c-using-io)

Answer (score 3):

```
string hex = String.Format("{0:X2}", hexIn);
```

With this formatting mask you will get for numbers from 0 to 32 (for example):

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F
```

I have added **2** (`0:X2`) because you mentioned that you are reading *bytes*.
Note, that for representing hex numbers also will be correct to add **0x** at the string beginning:

```
string hex = String.Format("0x{0:X2}", hexIn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
hex = hexIn.ToString("X");
```

or

```
hex = Convert.ToString(hexIn,16);
```