# Read hex in C# using IO

Tags: c#, io, hex

I'm new to C# moving from Java. I'm trying to read in a file using IO in HEX. When I read the first byte in I don't get what I'm seeing in my Hex editor.

I'm using

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileDirectory);
int hexIn;
String hex;

for (int i = 0; (hexIn = reader.Read()) != -1; i++){
    hex = Convert.ToString(hexIn, 16);
}
```

In Java I used

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
long length = file.length();

int hexIn;
String hex = "";

for(int i = 0; (hexIn = fis.read()) != -1; i++){

    String s = Integer.toHexString(hexIn);
    if(s.length() < 2){
        s = "0" + Integer.toHexString(hexIn);
    }
```

I hope this makes sense. Any help would be most apperciated :)

Thanks.

Comment: What are you getting compared to what you are expecting?

Comment: Hi, I'm getting FFFD not D0CF, it seems that the FFFD thats being read in is the ascii of D0CF, getting confused now ha ha

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't use a `StreamReader`—that's only for characters in a certain encoding (default UTF8). Use a [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0bs3w9t.aspx) class instead:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileDirectory, FileMode.Open);
int hexIn;
String hex;

for (int i = 0; (hexIn = fs.ReadByte()) != -1; i++){
    hex = string.Format("{0:X2}", hexIn);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, I was reading yesterday and got it in my head I had to use the Stream reader although my expericance in Java said otherwise. But thanks tested and working, any one else reading this don't forget to put... FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileDirectory, FileMode.Open); as it kicks up a fuss if you don't :)

Comment: also just for note incase other people use this you need to use hexIn = fs.ReadByte(); above so it will read the next byte in, just got me confused ofr a minute ha ha

Answer (score 0):

You need such `C#` code to achieve the same results as your Java code:

```
hex = hexIn.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0');
```

The `Convert.ToString` also works, but IMO using the native `ToString` of the integer is better practice.
Anyway you were missing the `PadLeft` part that indeed caused 15 to be 'f' instead of `0F`.

Comment: How do you read in a integer though? According to the documentation, the StreamReader.Read() method returns a ASCII value. That is most likely why he is not getting the same results as from his hex editor.

Comment: @Jack each character is represented by the ASCII value, HEX is just different base but it's the same thing exactly. Character with ASCII code 15 can be represented in HEX as `0F` and that's what hex editors are showing, but behind the hood it's the same thing. :-)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Oops... I thought he was trying to read in just integers :). Sorry, deleting answer :P.

Comment: Hi, thanks for such a quick reposnse, even when I use 

hex = hexIn.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0');

The first two bytes come as FFFD not D0CF as shown in the hex editor, I'm sure I'm just doing something stupid!

Comment: Thanks for your help Shadow, I got it working thanks to Mark ^^, oh thanks to Jack for having a go :)

Comment: @Pete cheers, wasn't aware of the Encoding issue - we all learn things here. :-)

Comment: @Shadow you're welcome, also just for note incase other people use this you need to use hexIn = fs.ReadByte(); above so it will read the next byte in, just got me confused ofr a minute ha ha

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard If I want to read a specific hex address like `05A231CA`, what should I do?

Comment: @AhmedSuror sorry no idea what you mean and pretty sure it got nothing to do with the question here.