# Keep the last eight bytes when reading raw image file with C#

Tags: c#

Im trying to read a raw image file with C# and keep the last 2 bytes, and last 8 bytes in a variable. However there is something wrong in my if-statement so the variables just appends.. Like this:

```
twoBytes= eightBytes=
twoBytes=00 eightBytes=00
twoBytes=0000 eightBytes=0000
twoBytes=000000 eightBytes=000000
twoBytes=00000000 eightBytes=00000000
twoBytes=0000000000 eightBytes=0000000000
twoBytes=000000000000 eightBytes=000000000000
twoBytes=00000000000000 eightBytes=00000000000000
twoBytes=0000000000000000 eightBytes=0000000000000000
twoBytes=000000000000000000 eightBytes=000000000000000000
twoBytes=00000000000000000000 eightBytes=00000000000000000000
twoBytes=0000000000000000000000 eightBytes=0000000000000000000000
twoBytes=000000000000000000000000 eightBytes=000000000000000000000000
twoBytes=00000000000000000000000000 eightBytes=00000000000000000000000000
twoBytes=0000000000000000000000000000 eightBytes=0000000000000000000000000000
twoBytes=000000000000000000000000000000 eightBytes=000000000000000000000000000000
twoBytes=00000000000000000000000000000000 eightBytes=00000000000000000000000000000000
twoBytes=0000000000000000000000000000000000 eightBytes=0000000000000000000000000000000000
twoBytes=000000000000000000000000000000000000 eightBytes=000000000000000000000000000000000000
twoBytes=00000000000000000000000000000000000000 eightBytes=00000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I want something like "twoBytes=55AA", and eightBytes="55AA454649205041"

My code:

```
// Read file, byte at the time (example 00, 5A)
FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\user\\image_files\\usb_guid_exfat.001", FileMode.Open);
int hexIn;
String hex;

String twoBytes = "";
String eightBytes = "";

for (int i = 0; (hexIn = fs.ReadByte()) != -1; i++)
{
    hex = string.Format("{0:X2}", hexIn);

    Console.WriteLine("twoBytes=" + twoBytes + " eightBytes=" + eightBytes);
  

    // Transfer two bytes
    twoBytes = twoBytes + hex;
    if (twoBytes.Length < 4)
    {
        if (twoBytes.Length > 6) { 
        twoBytes = twoBytes.Substring(2, 4);
        }
    }

    // Transfer eight bytes
    eightBytes = eightBytes + hex;
    if(eightBytes.Length < 8)
    {
        if (twoBytes.Length > 10) { 
        eightBytes = eightBytes.Substring(2, 8);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read hex in C# using IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612437/read-hex-in-c-sharp-using-io)

Comment: Your if statements don't make sense. If the length of `twoBytes` is less than 4, then it can't be larger than 6 at the same time.

Comment: as @HansKilian said, your conditions do not make sense, same for the `eightBytes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statements are wrong. A value can't be less than 4 and greater than 6 at the same time.

If length is <=4, you have 1 or 2 bytes, so you need to inspect only if length is grater than 4 (6,8,etc). Otherwise the value stays the same.

The code for inspecting string bigger than 4:

```
 twoBytes = twoBytes + hex;
 if (twoBytes.Length > 4) { 
     twoBytes = twoBytes.Substring(twoBytes.Length-4, 4);
 }
```

The similar with eightBytes.

Good luck!! :)