# C# read file as hex one byte at a time

Tags: c#, file, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read hex in C# using IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608824/read-hex-in-c-using-io)

Hi, I'm new to C# from Java and I have been stuck for the last two hours on something simple, or what should be so was wondering if someone would help me please :)

In Java I read in a file using the code beleow, it reads a given file in using hex, one byte at a time? What would be a way to do this in C#?

```
int hexIn;

File file = new File(filePath);

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

 for(int i = 0; (hexIn = fis.read()) != -1; i++){

   String s = Integer.toHexString(hexIn);
   if(s.length() < 2){
     s = "0" + Integer.toHexString(hexIn);
    }
}
```

Sorry if this seems dum I'm just stuck! Many thanks in advance!

:)

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608824/read-hex-in-c-using-io).

Answer (score 5):

Try this, it is quite a straight conversion from the code you posted:

```
        using (var file = File.Open("p:\\t.txt", FileMode.Open))
        {
            int b;
            while ((b = file.ReadByte()) >= 0)
            {
                string s = b.ToString("X");
                if (s.Length < 2)
                    s = "0" + s;

            }
        }
```

Comment: You can use the format string X2 to force 2 digits instead of prepending a zero.

Comment: and the formatting is done like so: string hex = String.Format("{0:X2}", hexIn);