# A stream type that supports partial viewing in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I'm working on a file reader for a custom file format. Part of the format is like the following:

```
[HEADER]
...
[EMBEDDED_RESOURCE_1]
[EMBEDDED_RESOURCE_2]
[EMBEDDED_RESOURCE_3]
...
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to open a new stream that its boundaries are only one resource, for instance `EMBEDDED_RESOURCE_1`'s first byte is at the 100th byte and its length is 200 bytes so its boundaries are `100 - 300`. Is there any way to do so without using any buffers?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at / possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012448/c-sharp-read-file-as-hex-one-byte-at-a-time

Comment: @gunr2171 this is not it, I'm trying to constraint the entire buffer to these boundaries (Not just reading a set amount of bytes at a time).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively - MemoryStream. 
Before reading the necessary number of bytes set the initial position of the position by the property - Position.

But it is necessary to read the entire file into MemoryStream.

Comment: Memory stream only operates on an in memory data, meaning I will need to read the data to a buffer first and only than creating a `MemoryStream` over that buffer.

Comment: Guess you do not want to read the entire file into memory. Then my simple solution does not suit you.